# TIN Interpolation - QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have a doubt and I would like to know if someone has the answer for it.
The TIN Interpolation tool let you add several attributes to be interpolated. While selecting several, the result is ONLY 1 raster. Wondering if the result is the average of all those selected attributes?

Comment: Good question. By the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html#tin-interpolation I am not sure if the meaning is that user could select several different layers and one attribute for each or if also selecting the same layer with different attributes is supposed to do something. The code in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-3_22/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/ui/InterpolationWidgets.py does not tell me much.
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-3_22/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/ui/InterpolationWidgets.py